# How to use WM_COPYDATA to send a string between Java programs using JNI?

Tags: c, winapi, java-native-interface

I want to send a simple string value between Java programs using Windows' Data Copy (`WM_COPYDATA`) using native C code using a JNI shared library. Essentially a Java program that wants to initiate comms can call a native method that will set up a message-only window that another Java program can come get the message from by also calling a native method (that exists in the same shared library).

I know I don't have a message loop and I don't know how to go about implementing this. I have seen examples online using `WndProc` callback function but I don't know if this is the appropriate way to go since this a message-only window (i.e. there are no visible UIs since my Java apps console-based.

Any help with code would be appreciated.

Set up:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_WindowsIPC_openDataCopy
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring message) {

 MSG msg;
 WNDCLASS WndClass;
 memset(&WndClass, 0, sizeof(WndClass));
 WndClass.lpfnWndProc = &DefWindowProc;
 WndClass.lpszClassName = L"Class";
 WndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

 HWND hwnd;
 LPCTSTR messageString = "A message";

 if (!RegisterClass(&WndClass)) {
   printf("failed to register class: %d\n", GetLastError());
   return -1;
 }

 hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WndClass.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 if (hwnd == NULL) {
   printf("Window Creation failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
   return -1;
 }

 while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
      TranslateMessage (&msg);
      DispatchMessage (&msg);
 }

  return 0; // success
}
```

Try get the message:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_WindowsIPC_getDataCopyMessage
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {

 HWND hwnd;
 hwnd = FindWindowEx (
    HWND_MESSAGE,
    0,
    0,
    0
 );

 LPCTSTR messageString = "A message";
 COPYDATASTRUCT cds;

 cds.dwData = 1;
 cds.cbData = sizeof(char) * (strlen(messageString) + 1);
 cds.lpData = (char*)messageString;

 if (hwnd == NULL) {
   printf("Couldnt find window: %d\n", GetLastError());
   return -1;
 } else SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hwnd, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds);

 LPARAM lParam;
 COPYDATASTRUCT* pcds = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)lParam;
 LPCTSTR lpszString = (LPCTSTR)(pcds->lpData);
 printf("%s\n", lpszString);

 return 0; // success
}
```

Comment: `WM_COPYDATA` is a cross-process message. You need to send it to a window in the target process - currently you're just sending it to yourself, which will achieve exactly nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I am calling `SendMessage` in the incorrect place? Forgive me, am totally new to winapi and there aren't many good tutorials out there.

Comment: You need a window at the other end to send the message to. Sending it within the same process is pointless.

Comment: I've edited my code. So the setup portion creates a window. The other end then tries to find the window and if successful calls `SendMessage`. The window then hangs as its presumably stuck in the message loop. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Based on your previous question there isn't much incentive for us here. You are going about this the wrong way completely. Make a pair of c++ programs that work and then port to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not asking `FindWindowEx()` to locate the *specific* `HWND_MESSAGE` window that `Java_WindowsIPC_openDataCopy()` creates.  You are asking it to locate the *first available* `HWND_MESSAGE` window, which could belong to anyone.  You need to specify the desired class name in the `lpszClass` parameter.

Also, you should use a more unique class name than `"Class"`.

On the receiving side, don't use `DefWindowProc()` itself for `lpfnWndProc`. You need to define your own windowproc function instead. Then you can actually process received `WM_COPYDATA` messages.  Pass any unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc()`.

Try something more like this:

```
LRESULT WINAPI MyWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  if (Msg == WM_COPYDATA)
  {
    COPYDATASTRUCT* pcds = (COPYDATASTRUCT*) lParam;
    if (pcds->dwData == 1)
    {
      LPCSTR lpszString = (LPCSTR) (pcds->lpData);
      printf("%.*s\n", lpszString, pcds->cbData);
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_WindowsIPC_openDataCopy
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring message)
{
  WNDCLASS WndClass;
  memset(&WndClass, 0, sizeof(WndClass));
  WndClass.lpfnWndProc = &MyWindowProc;
  WndClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("MyWindowsIPCClass");
  WndClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

  if (!RegisterClass(&WndClass)) {
    printf("failed to register class: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
  }

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, WndClass.lpszClassName, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if (hwnd == NULL) {
    printf("Window Creation failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
    return -1;
  }

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage (&msg);
    DispatchMessage (&msg);
  }

  return 0; // success
}
```

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_WindowsIPC_sendDataCopyMessage
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
  HWND hwnd = FindWindowEx (HWND_MESSAGE, 0, TEXT("MyWindowsIPCClass"), 0);
  if (hwnd == NULL) {
     printf("Couldnt find window: %d\n", GetLastError());
     return -1;
  }

  LPCSTR messageString = "A message";

  COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
  cds.dwData = 1;
  cds.cbData = sizeof(char) * (strlen(messageString) + 1);
  cds.lpData = messageString;

  if (SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, 0, (LPARAM)&cds) != TRUE) {
     printf("Couldnt send message\n");
     return -1;
  }

  return 0; // success
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Works great. Thanks so much. Am I correct in saying that Windows Procedures effectively "listen" for any messages received on a particular window, hence one is used in this scenario?

Comment: Whenever a message loop dispatches a message, the message is sent to the current window procedure of the window that is described in the message. By default, that procedure is the one specified in `RegisterClass/Ex()`, unless it has been replaced by subclassing (using `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubClass()`).  But yes, a window procedure receives all messages for the window, and can filter/process the messages as needed.